# How can I avoid CSS delay in Rails 3.2

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Update

If I add these lines, the delay goes away, but this seems to not be best practice?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/static_pages.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/dynamic_pages.css">
```

---

When the pages of my Rails 3.2 app load, the top nav menu and sub-menu, and other elements of pages first display with no CSS applied, and then instantly appear as they should.

I've heard of CSS compression and compiling/chaching. Is that how to avoid this?

One concern I have is that if I compile assets and turn on asset caching, and then if I change assets/css, then users will not get the newer versions, and my app work display correctly. Can you please comment on this as well?

Here is my HEAD:

```
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
</head>
```

Here is layout/_stylesheets.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's maybe not related to Rails, but to a phenomenon called "Flash of unstyled content" (a.k.a. FOUC).

If this is what is happening to you, then it's likely because you just have @import directives in your HEAD.
Try adding a LINK or SCRIPT tag and your problems should disappear.

There is a reference article here: [Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC) -- BlueRobot](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/)

Comment: Pierre's suggestion solved the problem, except for on one page. I don't know why, but when my advanced search page is rendered, this still happens. Nothing special about the page. It also renders via a yield in application layout like all the other pages. Strange. Anyone can comment on this?